# symfony translation for phrase with embedded link_to function

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How do you perform translation with an embedded `link_to` function in the template using Symfony 1.4?

Example:

> Please click `<php echo link_to('here', sfConfig::get('app_url') ?>` for additional info.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like this:

```
echo __("Please click "%placeholder%", array("%placeholder%" => link_to(__("here"), sfConfig::get('app_url'))))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works though I had to pick out the text from the link_to argument and create another translation for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
Please click <a href="<?php echo sfConfig::get('app_url') ?>"><?php echo __('here') ?></a> for additional info
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use:

```
Please click <?php echo link_to(__('here'), sfConfig::get('app_url') ); ?>
```